# PagedList working with ViewModels and .Skip().Take()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, mvvm, pagedlist

I have an Action in my Controller to get a list of `MyObjectViewModels`.

Inside that Action method, I call a method (Service layer) that fetches the relevant Models by applying a bunch of `LINQ` methods and returns a `IQueryable<MyObject>`.

Then I do some sorting on the returned `IQueryable` and afterwards, ideally, I would perform a `.Skip(...).Take(25)` in the resulting `IQueryable`, convert it to a List, iterate over the 25 `MyObject` elements and convert them into my `MyObjectViewModels` class. I'd then return a `PagedList` with those ViewModels:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(...parameters...)
{
    // Supose this returns 100000 records...
    IQueryable<MyObject> myObjs = _myService.GetMyObjects(...some params...);     

    // Sort and take only 25 (apply paging)
    IQueryable<MyObject> mySortedAndPagedObjs = myObjs.OrderBy(...);
    mySortedAndPagedObjs = mySortedAndPagedObjs.Skip(...).Take(25);

    List<MyObject> myObjsList = mySortedAndPagedObjs.ToList();
    List<MyObjectViewModel> myVMList = new List<MyObjectViewModel>();

    // *** Conversion loop ***
    foreach(MyObject myObj in myObjectList)
    {
       // ... convert the 25 MyObject to MyObjectViewModel 
       // and add them to the myVMList...
    }

    // Return a View with the PagedList
    return View(myVMList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    // --> The PagedList will not "know" that it is looking at 25 records of a 100000 long list!
}
```

This, seems incompatible with the [PagedList.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc) approach, which expects the `ToPagedList()` method to receive the *entire* set of objects (not just the 25 - I assume it internally calls the `.Skip().Take()` call itself). That would, however, force me to apply that conversion loop on the entire set of MyObject (!!) when I'd rather just do it for the 25 items I want to return at a time...

**How can I get my `PagedList` to show the `ViewModels` chosen from a subset (e.g. 25 records) of a table with lots of data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a case of [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) and I came up with the solution as I re-read the documentation when I was finished with my question. I'll post the Q&A anyway as it might be useful to someone in the future.

In order to accomplish the above scenario, I had to create and return a [`StaticPagedList`](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList#example-2-manual-paging).

> In some cases you do not have access something capable of creating an
>   IQueryable, such as when using .Net's built-in MembershipProvider's
>   GetAllUsers method. This method offers paging, but not via IQueryable.
>   Luckily PagedList still has your back (note the use of
>   StaticPagedList):

In my case, that means:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(...parameters...)
{

    // ... same as above ...

    // Create a StaticPagedList
    StaticPagedList<MyObjectViewModel> staticPagedList = new StaticPagedList<MyObjectViewModel>(myVMList , pageNumber + 1, pageSize, myObjs.Count());

    // Return a View with the StaticPagedList
    return View(myStaticPagedList);
}
```